# What happens to the file If the connection is lost while sending a file using scp.put()?

Tags: networking, ssh, file-transfer, scp

I need to implement file transfer using scp(ssh). I've tried to find information about this but i couldn't.

When the connection is lost during the file transferring using scp.put(), what happens to the file?

The file will be abnormally stored or lost?
If the file is stored abnormally, how can I resend it?

Thanks.

Comment: You will most likely get a truncated version of the file. But this in actually not related to Python and not a programming question.

Comment: I see.. thank you :)